# Istio Gateway and Traffic Routing does not work (deployed via Jenkins X/jx)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio, jenkins-x

So we have a `environment staging" repo which was created by jenkins x. In it we commit the following ymls to the`env/templates` folder. The kubernetes cluster is in AWS EKS.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: global-gateway
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: app-gateway
  namespace: global-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app-hosts
  namespace: jx-staging
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - app-gateway.global-gateway.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: test-app
        port:
          number: 80
```

The above YMLs work perfectly, and I can access the service when applied via kubectl apply -f .

However instead of creating them manually we commit and push it to the repo which triggers a JX job which runs successfully. Afterwards we can see that all of the Gateway and VirtualService has been deployed correctly. i.e. if we run `kubectl get Gateway` we can see our gateway.

However the URL does not work and does not redirect to the microservice after been applied from jenkins.

The command that jenkins seems to run is

`helm upgrade --namespace jx-staging --install --wait --force --timeout 600 --values values.yaml jx-staging .`

To try and diagnose the problem I deployed using kubectl and jenkins and diffed the output of `kubectl describe Gateway/VirtualService <name>`

The jenkins/heml deployment showed `Annotations:  <none>` while when deployed with kubectl it showed showed

```
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"networking.istio.
```

The `Resource Version` numbers were also different but I assume that is correct and alright?

EDIT:
The helm chart is as follows as well

```
description: GitOps Environment for this Environment
icon: https://www.cloudbees.com/sites/default/files/Jenkins_8.png
maintainers:
- name: Team
name: env
version: "39"
```

Please advice on how to get the istio gateway running with jx/helm.

Comment: Can you post the helm chart?

Comment: Added the definition given in the helm chart